# How does interspecies romance work between fantasy races?

Tags: fantasy-races, social-norms, sex, species, races

In my world, most of the fantasy races are very different from the typical. While there are some like ghouls, trolls, etc., there are animal people races instead of elves and dwarves. At some point, humans and the typical I mentioned will interact with them. They cannot actually crossbreed due to genetic reasons, but how would close love relationships between different species go, and with the physiological aspects, for realism? Would it be asexual and just be romantical, or would there be some sexual tension?

Comment: Public opinion, as the name states, it's an opinion: everybody has one. We don't answer on opinions.

Comment: Human relationships are complex, varied, and highly dependent upon the specific individuals involved in the relationship. This isn't going to change just because one of the partners isn't human. We do not allow questions about character driven issues. You can choose how you want to answer each of the multiple questions you ask any way you want. Questions where the answer are entirely based opinion or the discretion of the worldbuilder are off topic on this site. Please also note that we also have a strict one question per post policy.

Comment: The question is asking about how society would view things and the psychology

Comment: Taylor Anderson's [*Destroyermen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destroyermen) series features, among others, one or two bitter-sweet inter-specific romantic relationships which are more-or-less important to the plot, and, relevantly to the question, very well handled. You may want to check how he did it...

Comment: Take any topic and you will see that society has a wild and wide range on opinion on it, be it abortion or which side to hang the toilet paper roll. It's that wide range that you are asking about and that makes this question unfit for this community.

Comment: I think this much depends on the target audience of your fiction.  There is not a lot of sexuality in Tolkien.  Legolas fanfiction is a whole different matter.

Comment: I don't think Tolkien is the likely inspiration here @Willk this sounds more like something inspired by the Spell Singer books to me, plenty of cross species furry action going on in that.

Comment: [Opinion] If your "animal people" are essentially anthropomorphic animal-styled people, you can go as far as you like - relationships may be questionable, but not controversial by modern fiction standard. But if "animal people" are more like real animals, this may turn out to be too controversial for mainstream literature.

Answer (score 1):

**Depends on how you want *your* setting to look like.**

Your society could make the case that a relationship between two *sentient* beings is OK, and a relation between sentient and non-sentient beings isn't. Or the society makes the case that only a relationship between an interfertile couple is socially acceptable, possibly with the admonishment that sex is only for procreation, not for recreation.

If you look at human history, you will find many societies where same-sex relationships were socially taboo, even if they did happen behind closed doors all the time. And other societies where they were more or less accepted. You can also find societies where different-sex relationships of members of different 'races' were taboo, despite the fact that the couple could have offspring.

For that matter, you could have **different groups with different morals** in your setting. Different groups in the same city or county, perhaps elders condemning some matches which youngsters accept as a matter of course. Or a rural vs. city difference. Or there are **different reactions to different species**. Say most humans accept human-elvish relations, with a bit of envy towards the lucky human who 'snatched' an elvish lover. Humans accept human-dwarven relations, provided it is not a human woman who stands to inherit anything important. Orcs and trolls are shunned. Meanwhile, elves view other elves who fall in love with a human with a mixture of admiration for their romantic passion and pity for being with such a 'mayfly' partner -- for just a few decades.

And if relations are allowed, expect them to go physical. Humans in love like to touch.